# Outlook error 0x8004010F 'Outlook data file cannot be accessed.'

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange-2010

Outlook 2010 receiving the following error when trying to send emails using additional mail accounts. Sending from the default mail account works fine.

```
Task 'Info@domain.com reported error (0x8004010F) 
: 'Outlook data file cannot be accessed.'
```

Mail server is Exchange 2010. The user has full access and send permissions on required mailboxes.

I have re-created the user's Outlook profile twice.

Can someone please offer some ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got these problems before, although I'm not quite sure about the exact error message.

In my case I was only able to fix it by a complete removal and reinstallation of Outlook.

When you say you re-created the profile, did you completely remove the account from Outlook? Did the error came back before importing the old emails?

If you can answer both questions with a Yes I don't think there is another option but removing and reinstalling Outlook

Answer (score 1):

Picked this solution up a while back:

1. From Outlook click **File>Account Settings>Account Settings**
2. Click **Change Folder**
3. Click **New Outlook Data File** (This is just temporary)
4. Give it a name (I used "Test")
5. Click the **+** to the left of the folder name to expand the subfolders. Click **Inbox**. Click **OK**.
6. Then Click **Change Folder**
7. Click Select the one you want
8. Click the **+** to the left of the folder name to expand the subfolders. Click **Inbox**. Click **OK**.
9. Close Account Settings and click **send/receive**.

Comment: This worked, no need to reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click **Start** icon , and then click **Control Panel**.
2. Navigate to **Mail** item.
3. In the **Mail Setup - Outlook** dialog box, click **Show Profiles**.
   [[image: ]]
4. Select your current Outlook profile, and then click **Properties**.
   [[image: ]]
5. In the **Mail Setup - Outlook** dialog box, click **Data Files**. 
   [[image: ]]
6. Select the **Data Files** tab in the Account Settings dialog box, and then note the name and location of the default data file for your profile by clicking **Open File Location**.[[image: ]]

***Attention: The above actions are to identify the exact location of your current Outlook data file which is very essential for the next steps.***

7. create a new Outlook profile.
   7.1.  Return to the Mail-Setup Outlook dialog, click **Show Profile** again.
   7.2. On the **General** tab in the **Mail** dialog box, click
   **Add**.[[image: ]]
   7.3. In the **New Profile** dialog box, type a new profile name, and
   then click **OK**.
   7.4. In the **Add New Account** dialog box, type your email account
   information, and then click **Next**.[[image: ]]
   7.5. After your account is successfully configured, click **Finish**.

If you want to set the new Outlook profile as the default profile, follow these steps:
On the General tab of the Mail dialog box, select **Always use this profile**.

Click the drop-down under **Always use this profile**, and then select the new profile.

Click **OK** to close the Mail dialog box.

Now you can open your Outlook again. An the error would not appear again. Then you can follow the path mentioned above to import the previous Outlook data file. More details refer to : [[image: ]]

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can I just ask, are you affiliated in any way with the linked site? Because if you are, **you must disclose your affiliation in the answer itself**, otherwise, your answer may be flagged as spam. Please read [How to not be a spammer](https://superuser.com/help/promotion). Thanks!